# How long does it take to write a single character to an LCD 16x2 display with 8MHz AVR

Tags: c, time, avr, atmega, hd44780

I need to create some major improvements in my circut and I am not sure if the LCD display I am using is or is not the bottleneck.
Assuming well designed C code, how long would it take to set cursor position to (0,0), write 4 characters (or a single character) and set cursor to next line?
Does checking the busy flag increase/decrease the operation time?

I know measuring times like those can be problematic but I just need the order of magnitude. (Although if You have some experience with specific times please share your benchmarks).

Comment: "I am not sure if the LCD display I am using is or is not the bottleneck" - It is not. The LCD is a really slow device in terms of throughput (how many kB of data can you visualize per second on the display?). Then, communication is synchronous and clocked by the MCU, hence can be done at any timing or jitter the MCU desires. So the bottleneck is definitely in your code somewhere. Busy-waiting for slow devices like an LCD, for example, is never a good idea. Use timers, interrupts, state-machines or whatever else you can to do things while the display is 'busy'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 52 [the datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf) states the "Enable cycle time" t[cycE] is 500ns min. => At least 500ns are needed to send *one* word (4 or 8 bits) of data to the display.

Add to that the processing time for each operation (37µs for most). The return home command however takes 1500µs and hence dominates the processing time.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the HD44780 datasheet you can find the timing related information in Table 6:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf
Based on this table I estimate to set the cursor and write 4 characters should take approx. 300 us.